# Error: mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have to import mongoDB data into an elastic search, so I used the given conf with logstash:

```
input{
    jdbc{
        jdbc_driver_library => "D:/mongodb_unityjdbc_full.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://10.10.20.125:27017"
        jdbc_user => ""
        statement => "SELECT * FROM collection_name.documentname"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => 'http://localhost:9200'
    index => 'person_data'
    document_type => "person_data"
 }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

But I receive the following error:

> Error: mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?

Comment: did you miss the database name ? something like `"jdbc:mongodb://10.10.20.125:27017/database_name"`

Answer (score 2):

The file `D:/mongodb_unityjdbc_full.jar` either does not exist or is the wrong file.

In either case: you should download the official file and put it at the specified location. This is the official download URL: http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php

Answer (score 2):

The file path you have used is incorrect . Please use as:

```
jdbc_driver_library => "D:\mongodb_unityjdbc_full.jar"
```

Correct the backward slash to forward slash. 
Hope it works !

Comment: thanks for your answer...i tried this already but not worked...and later found that problem is in jdbc_driver_class

Comment: @PiraiSudie : Thanks for clarification !